# Tengo un problema con insertar datos en mysql y java

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

Resulta que yo tengo en Mysql, la tabla Canciones, cuya pk está compuesta por artista y nombre canción, tal que así.

[image: modelo lógico]

Cuando hago el ddl, pues me añade evidentemente, el campo email_artista, dando lugar que la tabla, cuando la inserto en mysqlWorkbench, esté formado por los campos:
Nombre, artista, estilocancion, arista_email, duración, foto y cantidadReproducciones.

Mi problema está ahora en java, pues no sé muy bien como insertar los campo porque Artista está en 2 ocasiones, una artista y otra artista_email. Además no le veo el sentido a tener que insertar el email, cuando la canción está formada por nombre y el artista.

```
public Cancion(String nombre, Blob foto, String ruta, Artista artista, 
            int duracion, ArrayList<Estilos> estilosCancion, int cantidadReproduccion) throws SQLException {
        super(nombre, foto, ruta);
        ObjetoConSonido ocs = new ObjetoConSonido();
        
        Statement smt = ConexionBD.conectar();
        if(smt.executeUpdate(
                "insert into usuario values ('"+nombre+"','"+artista+"','"+estilosCancion+"',"
                        + " '"+artista.getEmail()+"',"+duracion+",'"+foto+"',"+cantidadReproduccion+")"             
                )>0) {
            ocs.setNombre(nombre);
            this.artista = artista;
            this.estilosCancion = estilosCancion;
            //artista email
            this.duracion = duracion;
            ocs.setFoto(foto);
            this.cantidadReproduccion=cantidadReproduccion;
        }else {
            ConexionBD.desconectar();
            throw new SQLException("No se ha podido insertar la cancion "+nombre);
        }
        ConexionBD.desconectar();
    }
```

En mysqlWorkbench, la tabla es tal que así.

[image: tabla Cancion en MysqlWorkbench]

Alguien puede explicarme como habría que insertarlo correctamente ? debería modificar la bd para que la pk de canción solamente estuviera formada por nombre y asi, cuando se relacione, tuviera solamete nombre y artista_email ?

Comment: Lo normal en estos casos es tener en `Artista` una columna `artistaID` autoincremental que sea la llave primaria (PK), y declarar una restricción del tipo `UNIQUE` con las columnas `artista` y `artista_email`. Luego, para las relaciones en otras tablas usarás la columna `artistaID`. Si no lo haces así, tendrás que tener en las otras tablas las dos columnas que forman el índice `UNIQUE`, lo cual es poco práctico desde todos los puntos de vista.

Answer (score 0):

Lo normal en estos casos es tener en `Artista` una columna `artistaID` autoincremental que sea la llave primaria (PK), y declarar una restricción del tipo `UNIQUE` con las columnas `artista` y `artista_email`. Luego, para las relaciones en otras tablas usarás la columna `artistaID`. Si no lo haces así, tendrás que tener en las otras tablas las dos columnas que forman el índice `UNIQUE`, lo cual es poco práctico desde todos los puntos de vista.

Tu tabla `artista` se vería así:

```
artista

    artistaID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre    VARCHAR(50),
    email     VARCHAR(50),
    ... otras columnas,
    UNIQUE(nombre, email)
```

Y la tabla `cancion`, si una canción pertenece sólo a un artista:

```
cancion

    nombre    VARCHAR(50),
    artistaID INT,
    ... otras columnas,
    UNIQUE(nombre, artistaID)
```

La cosa se puede complicar, y en una `cancion` puede participar más de un `artista`. En ese caso, tienes que sacar la relación a una tabla conocida como *tabla asociativa*.

En ese caso, `cancion` queda así:

```
cancion

    cancionID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre    VARCHAR(50),
    ... otras columnas,
    UNIQUE(nombre)
```

Y la *tabla asociativa*:

```
cancion_artista

    cancionID INT,
    artistaID INT,
    UNIQUE(cancionID, artistaID)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu aportación me he es de gran ayuda. El proyecto está pensado para que una cancion, pertenezca a un solo artista. Me gustaría eso sí, a la hora de relacionar Artista, usar el campo nombre, más que el id. No obstante, tu comentario me ha sido de gran ayuda

Comment: @jucasmarcastilla el problema de usar sólo el `nombre` es que podría haber casos en que varios artistas tengan el mismo nombre (imagina que hay un `Pepe de los Palotes` en Venezuela y otro `Pepe de los Palotes` en España), en ese caso `nombre` no sirve como criterio de unicidad. Ahora bien, si en tu contexto no puede darse ese caso, puedes quitar `artistaID`, y declarar `nombre` como llave primaria (PK) en cuyo caso la restricción `UNIQUE(nombre)` ya no sería necesaria.

Comment: si si, tienes toda la razón. Estoy rediseñando ahora mismo la base de datos

Comment: @jucasmarcastilla tú podrías perfectamente usar dos columnas o más para definir los registros únicos, aún así, la ventaja de columnas `ID` es que en las tablas relacionadas usarías solamente esa columna. Si no tienes una columna `ID`, tendrías que repetir en las tablas relacionadas las `N` columnas que definen el registro único, lo cual es poco práctico. En una tabla relacionada puede haber millones de registros y si tú multiplicas por `N` las columnas eso se va a notar muchísimo. Esa es una de las grandes ventajas de tener un `ID` para estos casos, aparte de facilitar el mantenimiento, etc.

Comment: entendio.
Oye una duda, estoy haciendo el dao de un proyecto. Resutla que una de las tablas llamada listaCanciones, tiene un campo -- canciones ArrayList<Cancion>-- ¿tu sabes como se representa eso en la bd ? según tengo entendio, es un bucle,

Comment: El DAO **no se representa en la BD**, por decirlo de algún modo, es una forma de acceder a los datos. En el caso que expones, en el DAO definirías un método llamado más o menos: `getAllChansos()` el cual ejecutaría la consulta `SELECT * FROM canciones`, devolviendo una lista de objetos del tipo `Cancion`, pero, posiblemente vas a necesitar una lista de canciones por artista, pues tendrías **también** este método en el DAO: `getChansosByArtist(int artistaID)` que ejecuta una consulta así: `SELECT * FROM canciones WHERE artistaID = :artistaID` devolviendo una lista de objetos `Cancion` ...

Comment: ... filtrados por la columna `artistaID` de la tabla. Como ves, el DAO tiene un uso **contextual**, no puedes pensar en **reflejarlo en la base de datos**. El DAO se crea de acuerdo a las necesidad que tengas en tu aplicación, es decir, al modo en que necesites consultar los datos: en listas, filtrador por ID, el último registro, el primer registro, los primeros `N` registros, etc.

Comment: de acuerdo, lo he entendio